# Chrome or Firefox message - "Oracle it not initialized"

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, oracle

I have been visiting the Playstation Store and it behaves much differently that in Mac or Windows.

In the version I am using (Ubuntu 20.04 + Chrome 87) when I browse the site the "buy" buttons are not appearing. When I watch the developer tools, I get this error in the console:

> "Oracle is not initialized"

I thought this might be a Chrome issue, but apparently it also happens in Firefox, so it makes me think that this is a problem at the OS level.

Since this is a browser, it surprised me that it is not working cross-platform. What could be the reason for it?

[image]

Comment: This is not a Chrome problem. This is a website problem that has nothing to do with the coding of Chrome itself. Your best bet is to report it to the team that creates the website.

Comment: Did you try switching browsers, disabling extensions and user scripts?

Comment: Firefox had the same problem. I will update the question.

Comment: Seems like a reproducible issue. I tried switching user agents and the "Oracle is not initialized" disappeared.

Comment: @Kulfy You are right. I tested it and it disappeared. But the buttons for some items are still unvisible, and clicking them shows errors